# Building the tetrahedra of a set of random points - tetrahedralization

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, mesh, tetrahedra

I have a set of points (1 million of them, possibly more in the future, like 10 or 100 million) in 3D space that forms a sphere (they fill the sphere - they're not just on the surface) and I would like to build the tetrahedra that connect each sphere to its first neighbours... Looking for tetrahedralization, so far, all I found is :

- algorithms for meshing, but they fill empty spaces as far as I understand, whereas my points are fixed.
- algorithms for surface viewing, which is quite irrelevant
- algorithms for 3D images viewing (in the medical field, mostly) : which is closer but do not quite do the trick.

How can I do this?

2014-08-09 first of, thanks to you all for Your suggestions ! I was - and still am - on holidays and was just passing by to check whether anyone had answered... I am not disappointed !!!! :-)
I guess I'll first try CGAL, and will see from there. I have other data calculations on the same set of points in O(n2) that I expect will last about 1 week so a few hours would not be that bad. Minutes would be a dream come true !

Comment: *tetrahedralization*… my tongue crawled back in a dark corner and started crying…

Comment: http://lcni.uoregon.edu/~dow/Projects/Brain_casting/Point_cloud_to_mesh.html might be a good start.  Depending on your needs a 3d convex hull might suffice

Comment: You might want to look at the analogous 2D problem (filling with triangles) first: Delaunay Triangulation.

Comment: this is a good question. However it is not fitted for this site. Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the requirement to build a tetrahedron from the spheres?  Or is the requirement to build a tetrahedron inside the sphere that contains the most points?  Also, is it a regular tetrahedron?  If the requirement is my first question, the points inside the sphere do not come into the problem scope; only the sphere's location and volume.  Also, does the tetrahedron use the sphere's radius as a point?

Comment: What's the difference between your issue and the simplified problem: *Given 4 points, in 3D space, draw a tetrahedron*?

Comment: @bolov: No, this question is a fine fit for this site.  Neither of those sites are likely to be responsive.

Comment: How about using marching tetrahedra algorithm? It's similar to marching cubes and it's quite easy to implement.

Comment: @Jaa-c Isn't that for finding level-set surfaces?  You need a tetrahedralized space for that.  OP is trying to *make* such tetrahedralization in first place.

Comment: @emsr: True, I didn't read the question carefully...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be looking for a [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) algorithm in 3-space.

I hope you don't mind waiting a while, because a Delaunay triangulation of 100 million points is going to take quite some time.

[qhull](http://www.qhull.org) has an n-dimensional Delaunay implementation that you might try.  So does [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/).  Both packages will compute the Delaunay triangulation in O(n log(n)) asymptotic time, and CGAL can, with an appropriate choice of geometry kernels, do so in a numerically robust fashion.  (That is, it can automatically switch to exact arithmetic for those computations where inexact arithmetic produces an uncertain result.)

I would not recommend trying to implement a fast Delaunay triangulation yourself, even in two dimensions.  Terrifying things can happen when you need to evaluate predicates on the results of arithmetic.

Comment: A dt in 2d isn't so hard. After all it's just a bit geometry.

Comment: @Phpdna: It's easy enough in exact arithmetic.  You don't use exact arithmetic if you want your code to go fast.  With floating-point arithmetic, you run into the fundamental problem that you need to evaluate predicates on results of arithmetic in a consistent way.  Dealing with that is not easy.  (Put another way:  "I bet I can break your Delaunay triangulation code.")

Comment: You can also repair a bad triangulation!?

Comment: @Phpdna: How?  And what if it's not a triangulation?  And how do you detect "bad"ness?

Comment: @tmyklebu: just to clarify -- both CGAL and qhull implement fast `O(nlog(n))` algorithms. CGAL is also "robust" -- using exact arithmetic and symbolic perturbation (when necessary), ensuring that a valid DT is always produced, even when the input is degenerate. In practice, DT algorithms often exhibit `O(n)` scaling, so the time to tessellate 100 million points might not be as bad as you think, though it would definitely be measured in minutes, not seconds (http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/).

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda: Neat.  I guess CGAL must be doing something smarter than the sweep line/complicated data structure idea.  (And I was definitely thinking several hours rather than 15ish minutes for the running time.)

Comment: @tmyklebu: CGAL (as far as I'm aware) is actually just implementing an incremental tessellation based on the Bowyer-Watson algorithm. As per Phpdna's answer, the speed is obtained by inserting the points according to a kind of space-filling curve like ordering.

Comment: @DarrenEngwirda: OK, that works a *lot* better than I expected.  I don't see how to get an O(n log n) bound on any implementation of Bowyer-Watson, but that isn't very important.

Answer (score 1):

I use [tetgen](http://wias-berlin.de/software/tetgen/) for one of my project to do tetrahedralization. It works quite well and fast enough